# Force linebreak in URL with beamer, biblatex and biber

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber, urls

The URL in my MWE does not break because it fits on one line. This leads to three lines in the bibliography although two would suffice.

**How can I force it to break the URL to compress it to two lines?** I tried the ususal approaches, but they did not work, presumably because the URL is not long enough.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myurl.bib}
@online{longurl,
    author  = "Someone, Nice",
    title   = "This is my URL",
    year    = "2017",
    url     = "http://abc.efghij.kl.mn/~kausgdha/longsolong/anurlso/looong.html",
    urldate = {2017-11-27},
}

\end{filecontents}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens, spaces, obeyspaces}{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  breaklinks=true
}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myurl.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{longurl}
\frame[allowframebreaks]{\printbibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: url does not break, entry has three lines]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a quirk of `\raggedright` and where the breaks fall in this particular url. TeX doesn't seem to be able to find a good line break. You could try using the `ragged2e` package and `\RaggedRight` before `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{longurl,
    author  = "Someone, Nice",
    title   = "This is my URL",
    year    = "2017",
    url     = "http://abc.efghij.kl.mn/~kausgdha/longsolong/anurlso/looong.html",
    urldate = {2017-11-27},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\nocite{longurl}
\frame[allowframebreaks]{\RaggedRight\printbibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]